# How to choose the navbar logo in orbeon 4.5?

Tags: orbeon

In Orbeon Forms 3.9, there was an option to choose the logo just above the "Application Title". But I couldn't find that option in Orbeon 4.5.

Is there any way to choose the logo in Orbeon 4.5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The option disappeared in Orbeon Forms 4.0, as we thought this would be better done as a global or a per-app setting. However that setting hasn't been implemented yet.

So at this point there is no direct way to pick a logo via Form Builder.

This custom CSS can be used to hide the Orbeon logo:

```
.navbar .container img {
    display: none;
}
```

You should be able to add your own logo with CSS along the lines of:

```
.navbar .container {
    background-image: url(my-logo.png)
}
```

Some other CSS tweaks might be needed, but it's doable.

**UPDATE:**

I forgot about this property, which you can override:

```
<property
  as="xs:anyURI"
  name="oxf.fr.default-logo.uri.*.*"
  value="/apps/fr/style/orbeon-navbar-logo.png"/>
```

Comment: Thanks ebruchez, I have used the 'default-logo' property and its working fine.